# calling function in React SetState gives error that userName is unlabelled why?

Tags: reactjs, function, setstate

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

class Formhandler extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             userName:""
        }
    }

    changer=(event)=>{
        this.setState(()=>{
            userName : event.target.value
        })

    }

    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <label>UserName</label>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.userName} onChange={this.changer}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Formhandler
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an object inside the setState function but you are not that's the source of issue(syntax error).

1. use a function inside setState when your new state value would depend on your previous state value, where the function passed inside the setState will receive previous state as argument

```
changer = (e) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        userName : e.target.value
    })
   );
}
```

2. pass an object to update the state, use this when it doesn't depend on your previous state value.

```
changer = (e) => {
   this.setState({ userName: e.target.value });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because of invalid syntax.

Update **changer** function

```
changer = (event) => {
   this.setState({ userName: event.target.value });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

class Formhandler extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userName: "",
    };
  }

  changer(event) {
    this.setState(() => ({
      userName: event.target.value,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>UserName</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.userName}
          onChange={this.changer.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Formhandler;
```

It will work, compare your version and this